# IE 8 Crashes When Loading Site, Can't Debug -

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, crash, wordpress-thesis-theme

http://bizzocall.com/faq/ - Works well in all other browswers, but when I test it with the developer tools in IE 8 compatibility it just crashes.

I've looked at all the answers and it seems like each person has different problems (I've looked for stray commas, updated jquery, etc).

Any help is much appreciated!

UPDATE

I found a plugin that was calling jquery 1.4 (Dave's WordPress Live Search) and removed it.  Although the code seems cleaner it still pause IE 8.

UPDATE 2

Removing the plugin seemed to be the trick.

Just for those that find this post:  This was running wordpress with thesis installed.

Comment: it's working fine for me... what do you do to get the error?

Comment: How can you locate the error if it crashes?  Is there a "report?"  Yes, this is a real question.  LOL

Comment: Go to the developer tools then go to the JavaScript / Console tab. Press F12 for the shortcut

Comment: Did you try IE Safe Mode (without extensions)?

Comment: @Oscar: He's already using them.  **Read the question**.

Comment: Uh, i did. And he asked how to get a report **read the comments**.

Comment: No need to be snarky SLaks. We're all tring trying to help. And you haven't even offered a possible solution. Don't you have other posts to delete or flag or something rather than pick on people trying to help?

Comment: LOL  Thanks for the help, even the redundant help.   How do you run safe mode?  Again thank you for your time!

Comment: See @Dan Diplo answer below. I _believe_ that's "safe mode".

Comment: Ran in safe mode, still crashed.  Removed some of the redundant Jscript calls, but can't figure it out.

Comment: @Oscar: Sorry; I saw too many people assuming that he didn't have any details when he already had.  I have no idea what the problem is, so I can't offer anything other than safe mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes for me too in IE9 with IE8 mode. (see development tools -> `F12` ) If you disable javascript, it doesn't crash.. so it's a javascript issue. I see that you are loading 3 different version of jQuery, could be that?

EDIT. I was using the debugger, and got frozen during execution of jQuery 1.44 (You are loading this library in the footer from Google CDN )

Comment: I wasn't even really sure which one to get rid of, but I did notice that.  I'm a bit worried about changing too much since it runs well on the other browsers.

Comment: don't worry, I'm pretty sure it will be working still. And you make the website more light-weight. You are loading versions 1.44, 1.42 and 1.6. I will stick with the 1.44 version, and try removing the others. IF you see something stop working.. put the <script> of the jQuery before any other.

Comment: I was running 1.6 because I read (I think it was here) that it fixes some of the typical IE crashes.  I did remove the extra script though.

Comment: it's very new still 1.6 and most of your jquery plugins are oldish.. so could have compatibility issues. Aside of the jquery libraries that could conflict between each other. Luckily you didn't have problems in any other browser, but it produces random funny events to have multiple versions loaded of jQuery.

BTW. now doesn't crash anymore. You can accept the answer if you think it solved the problem

Comment: @corbacho - Thanks for the help, love the "answered" solved request.  Need to solve this.  I'll give out the love then.  =)

Comment: @corbacho - wish I had more rep to credit the other guys too, but this was the answer!  Thanks

Comment: k, though it was solved! and some brand-new users in stackoverflow forget about accepting answers ;)  Tomorrow I will check again. gn8 :)  (EDIT you can vote up for their answers to spread the love ;)

Comment: @corbacho - my rep isn't high enough, but thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that most likely you have a trailing comma, not necessarily a stray one. For example:

```
{
  "hello":"world",
  "foo":"bar"
}
```

Would work fine, but if you did:

```
{
  "hello":"world",
  "foo":"bar",
}
```

It would totally kill IE. Look for that or maybe give us more hints as to what the error is.

Comment: He doesn't even know WHAT the error is, so how would he know it isn't a syntax error?

Comment: Because then he would get an error.  His entire process is crashing.

Comment: It made me check other places out, so thanks for the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

When comment the script tag of fancybox, IE doesn't crash. But I don't know what is the cause.

You call jquery twice: jquery 1.6 and jquery 1.4.4. Seems this cause the crash. But if you disable jquery 1.4.4, fancybox still causes the crash. Disabling jquery 1.6 avoid the crash.

Answer (score 1):

My IE (IE 8.0 @ Windows Server 2003) is not killed when I enter the page.

However the Javascript seems to keep on running forever, because IE offers me to "Stop running script ... causing Internet Explorer to run slowly ... ". There's a Javascript error indication too. It says:

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; Trident/4.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Fri, 13 May 2011 20:08:46 UTC


Message: Permission denied
Line: 133
Char: 374
Code: 0
URI: http://bizzocall.com/faq/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4
```

You said you've updated JQuery, but 1.4.4 doesn't seem to be the latest version, does it?

---

UPDATE:

I ran the Developer Tools (F12) to get the call stack and one of the entries in the stack (just in the middle) is:

```
    //jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js lines 1040-1045 in the $.fancybox.init
    $('body').append(
        tmp = $('<div id="fancybox-tmp"></div>'),
        loading = $('<div id="fancybox-loading"><div></div></div>'),
        overlay = $('<div id="fancybox-overlay"></div>'),
        wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-wrap"></div>')
    );
```

---

UPDATE2:

I give up. My Javascript/JQuery knowledge is too limited. And the minified JQuery code doesn't seem to help either. Debugging through things like `this.each(function(e){var g=f(this);a[0]=j.call(this,e,c?g.html():b),g.domManip(a,c,d)})` doesn't seem to be the easiest thing in the world.

I suggest running the same code with a single JQuery instance (one version, it may be 1.4.4 if that's your pick) in development (unminified) version. Problems may arise if the bug doesn't happen then.

Comment: Since my base template isn't calling this it's got to be from the plugins?  I'm actively searching the plugins to see which one is calling this.

Comment: @Gzegorz - Thanks what looks like a totally awesome answer, but what does it mean?

Comment: I am debugging to see what it does. It looks like it never gets out of this `.append` call.

Comment: Discovered that "Dave's WordPress Live Search" made this call to 1.4.4 and removed Dave and his plugin. --- Testing now.

Answer (score 1):

Dave from "Dave's WordPress Live Search" here. Just wanted to add a few comments:

- Dave's WordPress Live Search doesn't "call jQuery 1.4". It tells WordPress to load the version of jQuery it ships with, currently 1.4.4. jQuery 1.6 isn't supported natively by WordPress until version 3.2 ships next month. The preferred way to use an alternate version of jQuery is to "deregister" the included jQuery and register your own version in its place. Adding the following to your theme's functions.php file should take care of it:

  ```
  if ( !is_admin() ) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery'); //deregister current jquery
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.js', false, '1.6', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  }
  ```
- Someone recently figured out that the jQuery Dimensions plugin included with Dave's WordPress Live Search was causing IE8 to hang. This was needed way back when I first wrote this plugin because WordPress shipped with an ancient (even for the time) version of jQuery. The functionality this jQuery plugin provides was merged into jQuery core a long time ago, and since I've dropped support for WordPress < 2.9, it's not needed anymore. Give Dave's WordPress Live Search v2.1 a spin.

Comment: So it was updated then, I loved the plugin, but it was causing some major havoc, thanks for updating this thread!

Answer (score 0):

Try running IE without add-ons. Often the reason for a full-blown crash is an add-on interfering with something. To do this:

Start > All Programs > Accessories > System Tools > Internet Explorer (No Add-ons)

If you can't find that then go to a run promt (*Windows Key + R*) and type `iexplore.exe -extoff`

Comment: Ran in safe mode, got further, but it just hangs and has to be force closed.  The background doesn't load which makes me think it's the supersized code, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I eventually tracked it down to an out of date version of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). Mine was at `2.0.6` and can confirm that version `2.5.3` fixed the issue completely.